# Error implementing differentiating matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib, numeric

I am trying to take derivatives using a differiating matrix. 
Having now managed to get the differentiation matrix, I am not able to compute the derivatives. 
Note I had previously asked:
[Constructing a Multidimensional Differentiation Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792037/constructing-a-multidimensional-differentiation-matrix)

My current code is as follows

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


N = 20
x = np.linspace(-1,1,N)


f1 = np.sin(3*x) # exact function 
df1 = 3*np.cos(3*x) # exact derivative for comparison sake 

def Dmatrix(N,f): 
    m_ij = np.zeros((N,N,N))
    fprime = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(0,N-1):
        x = np.cos([(2*i + 1)/2*N])
        for j in range(0,N-1):
            for k in range(0,N-1):
                m_ij[i,j,k] = -(2/N)*((k*np.sin(k*np.pi*(2*i + 1)/2*N))*(np.cos(k*np.pi*(2*j +1))/2*N)/(np.sin(np.pi*(2*i + 1)/2*N)))
                fprime[j] += f[x[j]]*m_ij[i,j,k]
    return m_ij,fprime

dij,fprime = Dmatrix(N,f1) 

plt.plot(x,f1,'b')
plt.show()
plt.plot(x,fprime,'k')
plt.show()
plt.plot(x,df1,'r')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
  File "/home/~", line 20, in Dmatrix
    fprime[j] += f[x[j]]*m_ij[i,j,k]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Note with the altered Dmatrix function without the collocation point x, code is as follows:

```
def Dmatrix(N,f): 
    m_ij = np.zeros((N,N,N))
    fprime = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                m_ij[i,j,k] = -(2/N)*((k*np.sin(k*np.pi*(2*i + 1)/2*N))*(np.cos(k*np.pi*(2*j +1))/2*N)/(np.sin(np.pi*(2*i + 1)/2*N)))
                fprime[j] += f(x[j])*m_ij[i,j,k]
    return m_ij,fprime
```

This gives  fprime with a similar plot for the exact solution f1, which is wrong as I want to obtain the derivative of the exact solution, i.e df1.

I am not sure why this happens. 
Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: So have you checked the indices in the problem line?  What are `j`, `x[j]` and `i,j,k`?  You have the code that's running up to  that point.  I may be able to copy-n-paste and find that out myself, but it would be nice if you did the checking yourself!

Comment: OK, I was able to run your code and do a diagnostic print.  From that it's obvious that `x[j]` is not a valid index!

Comment: Also note that `x` has shape `(1,)` so for any `N` larger than `2` this will fail even with the correction

Answer (score 0):

Changing

> fprime[j] += f[x[j]]*m_ij[i,j,k]

To

> fprime[j] += f[x[0]]*m_ij[i,j,k]

Outputted the following three images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xfq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtcXm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsLvz.png)

Not sure if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Radonic for spotting this mistake! Have you done anything else? I have changed this according to your suggestion but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: The only error I get was that an index was out of range since x is an array of one element and after performing the above mentioned changes the code worked. Are the images I enclosed your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

When I add a `print` to your code:

```
            print(i,j, k, x[j])
            fprime[j] += f[x[j]]*m_ij[i,j,k]

1531:~/mypy$ python3 stack59759031.py 
0 0 0 -0.8390715290764524
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack59759031.py", line 25, in <module>
    dij,fprime = Dmatrix(N,f1) 
  File "stack59759031.py", line 22, in Dmatrix
    fprime[j] += f[x[j]]*m_ij[i,j,k]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

So `x[j]` is a float value, which is not a valid index!

Comment: Thanks, I will think further about this. I was not even not sure how should I index the original function to my derivative matrix. The formula states it has to be ``` f(x_j) *Dmatrix{i,j}``` where f is the original function.